# Handling duplicates when using Partially Matched Crossover for Genetic Algorithm

Tags: python, optimization, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I am new to Genetic Algorithms and am working on a python implementation. I am up to the crossover step and am attempting a Partially Matched Crossover. For my final output I am hoping for a list that contains no duplicated numbers. However, in some cases, I am introducing duplicates.
For example, Take the lists

`Mate 1 [1,2,3,5,4,6]`

`Mate 2 [6,5,4,3,2,1]`

If the crossover portion is `[3,5,4] -> [4,3,2]`

Then the offspring before mapping becomes `[1,2,4,3,2,6]`. My understanding of the algorithm is the mapping outside the crossover is  `4 -> 3, 5 -> 3 and 2 -> 4`. However, this results in an output of `[1,4,4,3,2,6]` which has duplicates and is missing a 5.

How do I work around this problem? Does the first 4 just become a 5? And how would this scale to larger lists that might introduce multiple duplicates?

Comment: In your question it looks like you are mapping 3 to both 4 and 5? And also you are mapping 4 to both 2 and 3? This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2ft8AG8JKE) shows how mapping in PMX works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure you have implemented it right:

for Partially Matched Crossover ([see explanation](http://www.wardsystems.com/manuals/genehunter/crossover_of_enumerated_chromosomes.htm)), if your crossover points are 2 and 5 as suggested in the example then you can only obtain

```
offspring1 = [6, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1]
offspring2 = [1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 6]
```

if you select `3,5,4` from mate1 and fill the rest in the order of mate2 you will get offspring 1 but if you select `4,3,2` from mate2 and fill the rest in the order of mate 1 you will get offspring 2

See implementation below:

```
mate1 = [1,2,3,5,4,6]
mate2 = [6,5,4,3,2,1]


crossoverpoint1 = 2
crossoverpoint2=5
child = []

#fill in the initial genes in order of mate1
count = 0
for i in mate1:
    if(count == crossoverpoint1):
        break
    if(i not in mate2[crossoverpoint1:crossoverpoint2]):
        child.append(i)
        count= count+1

#select the genes within the crossover points from mate2          
child.extend(mate2[crossoverpoint1:crossoverpoint2])

#fill in the remaining genes in order of mate1
child.extend([x for x in mate1 if x not in child])

print(child)
```

output:

```
[1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 6]
```

to obtain offspring1 swap mate1 for mate2.
you can also try different crossover points, let me know if this helps